# How do I change a date formatted like this "2017-03-24" into a proper date format in SAS?

Tags: sas

I need to change what it is currently at into the date9 format.

```
input Company_Name$ 1-58 Form_Type$ 59-70 CIK Date_filed$ 86-96 File_Name$ 118-141;
length Date_filed $10.;
format Date_filed yymmdd10.;
ndate=put(Date_filed, yymmdd10.);
```

this is what I have, but it doesn't work. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: You cannot attach a numeric format like `YYMMDD` to a character variable. Why are you reading the value as a character string instead of a date to begin with?  Also why are you reading 11 columns if the dates are in a style  that only takes 10 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS stores dates in numeric variables as the number of days since 1960.  Once you have a valid date value you can attach any of the many formats that change how the value is displayed.  To read directly from the source file into a date value using an INFORMAT that is appropriate for the value.  Note that you cannot combine an informat with the column range in the input statement. Instead you can use @ to position at the first column of the date string and then use formatted input.  Also you did not tell INPUT what columns to read for the variable `CIK`.

```
input Company_Name $ 1-58 Form_Type $ 59-70
      CIK 71-85 @86 Date_filed yymmdd10. 
      File_Name $ 118-141
;
format Date_filed date9.;
```

Note you were reading 11 columns before but date strings in YYYY-MM-DD style only need 10 columns, so check if your date strings are in columns 86-95 or columns 87-96.  If you don't read the right columns you might miss the second digit of the day of the month or the first digit of the year.